# My simple jquery dropdown function is bugged and glitchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a simple jquery dropdown function that will let me show blocks of info on hover over menu elements. At this point what I made so far is bugged and glitchy if you mouse over too fast. Also the dropdown seems to stay visible only while hovering the element and not on its child.

Maybe someone could have a quick look at the code and suggest how to implement some sort of flags so the menue does not go away easy and dont get glitchy on multiple mouse hovers.

You will probably ask why I dont do it by pure css, unfortunately I need older browsers support and prefer to wrap it one function.

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/inedoy/1

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    body {margin:60px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
    ul {margin:0;padding:0;} 
    ul li {
        position:relative;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px 0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .dropdown {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        padding:20px;
        top:40px;
        left:0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li class="drop">Some link
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

dropdown('.drop','.dropdown');

function dropdown(hoverElement,toShow){ 
    $(hoverElement).hover(function(){                       
        $(toShow).stop().slideDown();                   
    },function(){       
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(toShow).stop().hide();    
        },300);     
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

One trick involves resetting the timer when the mouse is still inside, and starting the timer when it's out.

```
$(function() {
  var myTimer;
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".drop", function() {
    parent = this;

    // Close the other dropdowns except this one..
    $(".drop").not(parent).find(".dropdown").hide();

    // Show dropdown
    $(".dropdown", parent).show();

    // Clear the timer so it doesnt close.
    clearTimeout(myTimer);

   }).on("mouseleave", ".drop", function() {
    parent = this;

    // Start the timer
    myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".dropdown").hide();
    },560)
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/inedoy/42/

Comment: just declare myTimer before the $(document).. var myTimer. http://jsbin.com/inedoy/39/

Comment: Unfortunatly your code does not work with more then one item and the timeout is not cleared http://jsbin.com/inedoy/41

Comment: Hard to tell without the whole DOM. Here's a revised version that also closes previous dropdowns http://jsbin.com/inedoy/42/

Answer (score 1):

Did some changes to your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
    body {margin:60px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size:12px;}
    ul {margin:0;padding:0;} 
    ul li {
        position:relative;
        list-style-type: none;
        padding:5px 0;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .dropdown {
        display:none;
        position:absolute;
        width:200px;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        padding:20px;
        top:25px;
        left:0;
    }

  .drop
  {
    /*border: 1px solid;*/
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li class="drop">Some link
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
                <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
                <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
            </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

dropdown('.drop','.dropdown');

function dropdown(hoverElement,toShow)
  { 
    var intervalId = 0, sliding= false;

    $(hoverElement).hover(function()
    {                       
        clearTimeout(intervalId);
        if(!sliding)
        {
          sliding = true;
          $(toShow).stop().slideDown( function(){sliding = false;});                        
        }

    },function(){       
        intervalId = setTimeout(function()
        {
            sliding = false;
            $(toShow).stop().hide();    
        },300);     
    });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/inedoy/36/edit